# "had been" VS "had"

Tags: past-perfect

> It was amazing that infectious diseases which **had proven** invulnerable to drug treatment until then could be effectively treated.
>
> It was amazing that infectious diseases which **had been proven** invulnerable to drug treatment until then could be effectively treated.

I know that the second sentence is wrong, and the first is correct, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when used in this context the verb

```
To prove
```

Means

```
To be found either by trial or by experience to be
```

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/proven

```
... infectious diseases which had proven invulnerable ...

... infectious diseases which had been found by experience to be invulnerable ...
```

Adding the verb to be makes it non-sensical because

```
... infectious diseases which had been proven ...
```

would become

```
... infectious diseases which had been been found by experience ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We can prove something (transitive). Through scientific method, we can *demonstrate the truth* of the thing.

Something can prove to be true or false or to possess a certain characteristic or identity. It is something whose truth or falsehood or whose characteristic or identity *has become evident*.

The passive is formed from the transitive, "we prove something": something *has been proven* (by someone) ...

Both the transitive and the intransitive accept a predicate complement, either in the form of the predicate adjective (true, false, some other attribute) or in the form of **to be** +  adjective.

When an *identity* is expressed, we normally use **to be**:

> The toxin proved to be arsenic.
>
> The toxin was proven (by the forensic toxicologist) to be arsenic.

When a *characteristic* is expressed, we can choose the adjective alone or **to be** + adjective:

> The climb proved difficult.
>
> The climb proved to be difficult.